# How to load specific files in Pig stored at different level using single load command

Tags: apache-pig

I am having below folder structure.

```
/data/day1/abc.csv
/data/day1/def.csv
/data/day2/abc.cvs
/data/day2/def.csv
/data/old/dayxx/abc.csv
/data/old/dayxx/def.csv
```

I am not able to load all abc.csv files using single pig load command.
If i use

```
LOAD '/data/*/abc.csv' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage()
```

its missing data under /data/old/dayxx directory.

Is it possible to load all abc.csv files at different levels using single pig load command?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with this directory structure using just Pig.

Comment: What do you mean by just pig, What else can be used? any workaround?

Comment: I mean you can write a Custom Loader UDF but I think it'll be better to use multiple relations to load different files or move all `abc.csv` under one directory using a shell script (or something else) and then loading it using pig.